# NLA tracks, how do they work? Why all these tracks?

Tags: nla-editor

[image]
I have seven tracks and I don't understand why.

My shape key for my "Body" mesh all have bone drivers so there isn't and won't ever be any keyframes to go with it so why do I see a key track?
I don't have a key named Key.001 yet I have a track for that too. Why?
Why does "Body" have a dope sheet track (3 diamond icon) called {no action}?
I imported a BHV called carefulsneak, there are 2 tracks with a silver and gold star. 
Why does it also have a dope sheet track (3 diamond icon) called {no action}?
Why is there a carefulsneak.001 and is transparent on a track called NlaTrack.001?

Honestly when I read the Blender manual on NLA tracks I litterally say "What?" to every sentence. Intuitive so far, it is not.